# Error adding/removing Outlook Distribution List users through .NET

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, active-directory, distribution-list

I am a co-owner of several Outlook Distribution Lists (DL's).  I can edit them in Outlook, adding and removing members directly in there.  However, I cannot edit them through a simple .NET program:

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

namespace DL_Remove_User
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                RemoveUser("My Distribution List", "jimtut");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static void RemoveUser(string dl, string username)
        {
            using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "CORP"))
            {
                GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, dl);
                bool result = group.Members.Remove(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
                Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
                group.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This same code works on many other DL's, but for a couple, I get the message "Access is Denied".  Full stack trace:

```
at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.SetInfo()

at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.CommitChanges()

at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.UpdateGroupMembership(Principal group, DirectoryEntry de, NetCred credentials, AuthenticationTypes authTypes)

at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SDSUtils.ApplyChangesToDirectory(Principal p, StoreCtx storeCtx, GroupMembershipUpdater updateGroupMembership, NetCred credentials, AuthenticationTypes authTypes)

at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.Update(Principal p)

at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.Save()

at Department_Distribution_Lists.Program.RemoveUser(String dl, String username) in Program.cs:line 483
```

Of course, "Access is denied" does indicate a permission problem, but I can edit these DL's directly in Outlook.  I can even query the DL "owners" in AD/LDAP, and I'm in the collection "msExchCoManagedByLink".

Any thoughts on why I can edit in Outlook but not through .NET?

Comment: I was looking at this yesterday, and it really stumped me. I don't have anything. Adding someone as the manager of a group should give them permissions to edit the members. Maybe check the Security tab of the group and make sure you do indeed have permissions to write to the `member` attribute.

Comment: Where do you find the Security tab?  I don't see it when looking at the Group using the "Active Directory Users and Computers" tool, nor in Outlook.

Comment: Using .NET's DirectoryServices, I was able to compare all the properties (all that are available in .NET) between a DL that I can edit this way and one of these troublesome DL's.  I can't see a difference in any properties, other than the expected ones like Name, Created, etc.

Comment: To see the Security tab in Users and Computers, you need to enable "Advanced Features" from the View menu of the main window.

Comment: All permissions are enabled, except Full Control, Delete Subtree, and Delete all Child Objects.  It looks exactly the same as other DL's that I can modify.  And I can modify the ones with this problem directly in Outlook, just not through .NET.  (BTW, I get the same error in Perl too, so I don't think it's just .NET.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  I was confused by this permissions problem since I could edit the DL in Outlook, but not thru .NET.

I started looking for differences between the DL's that I could edit thru .NET and those that I could not, and found the difference was represented in the AD property shown in this GUI as "Manager can update membership list":

[image: dl]

Even though I was the "manager" (list owner), if the DL didn't have that property set, I could ONLY edit in Outlook.

I didn't want to have to visually check all the DL's, so I wrote the following code to detect the "real" owners/editors of a DL:

```
    static List<string> GetGroupOwners(GroupPrincipal group)
    {
        List<string> owners = new List<string>();
        DirectoryEntry deGroup = group.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
        ActiveDirectorySecurity ads = deGroup.ObjectSecurity;
        AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = ads.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
        Guid exRight_Member = new Guid("{bf9679c0-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2}");

        foreach (ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ar in rules)
        {
            if (ar.ActiveDirectoryRights.HasFlag(ActiveDirectoryRights.GenericWrite) || (ar.ObjectType.Equals(exRight_Member) && ar.ActiveDirectoryRights.HasFlag(ActiveDirectoryRights.WriteProperty)))
            {
                string friendlyName = "";
                try
                {
                    friendlyName = ar.IdentityReference.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value;
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                owners.Add(friendlyName);
            }
        }
        return owners;
    }
```

If you want to know who has Outlook-based edit access, that's different:

```
    static List<string> GetGroupOwnersOutlook(GroupPrincipal group)
    {
        List<string> owners = new List<string>();
        DirectoryEntry deGroup = group.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
        System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection r = deGroup.Properties;
        foreach (string a in r["managedBy"])
        {
            owners.Add(a);
        }
        foreach (string a in r["msExchCoManagedByLink"])
        {
            owners.Add(a);
        }

        return owners;
    }
```